# how to get rid of EOF:ran out of input error while unpickling python object

Tags: python, pickle

here i m pickling my object
pickling our model

```
with open("my_xgmodel.pickle","wb") as f:
pickle.dump(mdl_re_2_7200_,f)
```

loading an pickle object

```
with open("my_xgmodel.pickle","wb") as f:
my_xg_model=pickle.load(f)
```

**i know EOFError: Ran out of input" means that i am trying to read empty file but why my pickle object is becoming an empty**

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("my_xgmodel.pickle","wb") as f:
    my_xg_model=pickle.load(f)
```

You can't read from a file that was opened in "w" mode. Try opening in "r" mode instead.

```
with open("my_xgmodel.pickle","rb") as f:
    my_xg_model=pickle.load(f)
```